# fluent-ffmpeg display_aspect_ratio not changing

Tags: node.js, video, ffmpeg, ffprobe, fluent-ffmpeg

Hi everyone i'm trying to resize width and height of certain input with fluent ffmpeg to 768x1366 (basically to show it in vertical mode), so i have to also change its display_aspect_ratio which i happen to know is 0.562225476.
The issue here is that, according to fluent-ffmpeg [doc](https://github.com/fluent-ffmpeg/node-fluent-ffmpeg#aspectaspect-set-output-frame-aspect-ratio), if i set a fix size, it wont change the aspect ratio, but it wont work either if I use `?` to automatic mode. This is my code:

```js
ffmpeg({source: req.file.path}) 
            .withFps(30)
            .toFormat('mp4')
            .size("768x?")
            .aspect(0.562225476)
```

Console command:
`ffmpeg -i tmp/video.mp4 -y -r 30 -filter:v scale=w=768:h=1366 -f mp4 ./src/internal/media/video.mp4`

So when i check the display_aspect_ratio with `ffprobe` it's still 4:3 (as source file).

If I do not add the `.aspect()` option, the command is exactly the same...so it's not considering it.

I've also tried:

```js
ffmpeg({source: req.file.path}) 
            .withFps(30)
            .toFormat('mp4')
            .size('768x1366')
            .addOptions('-vf setdar=0.562225476')
```

And command here ends up being `ffmpeg -i tmp/video.mp4 -y -r 30 -filter:v scale=w=768:h=1366 -f mp4 -vf setdar=0.562225476 ./src/internal/media/video.mp4`, so it seemed ok, but when I check with ffprobe it did not apply width and height changes.

The command I really need is some kind of : `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf scale=768:1766,"setdar=0.562225476" video2.mp4` which changes **both**, widthXheight and display_aspect_ratio

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, your last call is exactly what you need to do (except you don't need the double quotes around `setdar`).

[edit]
Can't you just do this?

```
ffmpeg({source: req.file.path}) 
            .withFps(30)
            .toFormat('mp4')
            .addOptions('-vf scale=768:1766,setdar=0.562225476')
```

[/edit]

I don't know how to do that with `fluent-ffmpeg`, but once upon a time, I submitted [`kiss-ffmpeg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kiss-ffmpeg) to NPM to translate console ffmpeg command easier to JavaScript. It's no longer maintained (as I moved to Python since) but I see people are still downloading so should be still usable.

With `kiss-ffmpeg`, you can specify your `vf` option by

```js
ffmpeg.outputs = [
  { url: "video2.mp4", options: { "vf": "scale=768:1766,setdar=0.562225476" } }
];
```

See the NPM readme for how to set up the rest of the call.

Comment: Thank's man, but i can not risk my app with package it's no longer maintained.

Comment: Understand. Actually, now I looked at your code closely (should've done first) you may have an easy fix. See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Yes, you were right. I also didn't realize about that workaround. Either way, i will still keep the thread opened without solution in order to understand the library im using. Tanks a lot!